# Ionic app install and run

Tags: ionic-framework

I've just started learning Ionic. I've installed Ionic and other stuff with `npm install`. 
After running my default application in the middle Node prompt is not working I'm unable to type anything.

Can anyone explain to me what might be the problem?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you close the process with Ctrl+C ?

Comment: Why would you want to type something? Ionic is a frontend framework that allows you to write hybrid mobile app.
Regarding your screenshot, everything is good, you can access to your app in a browser navigating to `http://localhost:8100`

Comment: once you run `ionic serve` under your project folder, the app would be popup via your browser.

Comment: @junior Gantin thanks

Comment: @zooly thanks. actually i want to run default sidemenu. i tried like this `myApp sidemenu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps for seeing something in your browser:

I assume that you already have installed `ionic` & `cordova`.

- Create your Ionic project `ionic start yourAppName sidemenu`
- Go in your app folder `cd yourAppName`
- Run your app `ionic serve`

After some seconds, it should open a browser tab with your app running.

For more details, please read [Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/) and [Get started](https://ionicframework.com/getting-started).